# Runtime.getruntime.exec("cls/clear"); not working in Windows to clear console

Tags: java, console

I have tried many times to clear the console and have written this **Runtime.getruntime.exec("cls");** but did not get any result, means the console is not being cleared in **Windows**.

Comment: Have you tried just with `Runtime.getruntime.exec(“cls”);`??

Comment: `Runtime.exec()` will execute the specified command in a separate process... Not in the same as your Java program is running...

Comment: then what to do to clear the console?

Answer (score 0):

`System.out.print("\b")` might do the trick. One `\b` for each character printed.

```
System.out.print("Foo");
System.out.print("\b\b\b");
System.out.print("Bar");
```

This prints "Bar"

```
String foo = "Foo";
System.out.print(foo);
for (int i = 0; i < foo.length(); i++) {
    System.out.print("\b");
}
System.out.print("Bar");
```

Same result using a loop.